# How to convert .csv or .mat file to ros?

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, rosbag, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I collect the odom and IMU data by dspace microautobox and at the same time I collected lidar data directly on ROS.

The odom data is .mat file now and it can be converted to .csv file. The lidar data has been recorded as a rosbag file.

Now I want to first convert the odom data to something available for ROS and then merge the two data to a single rosbag file. How can I make it?

I searched online for a long time but only can find how to convert rosbag file to other formats...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256412/how-to-convert-.csv-or-.mat-file-to-ros?/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See #q119211 and #q233042 (via #q249059) for related questions.

To summarise: a simple Python script that reads in your CSV and uses the rosbag API to convert everything to a rosbag is probably easiest.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-07**:
Thanks, I will try that

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-07**:
By the way, do you have any suggestion about how to correlate dspace with ROS? I want to implement real time finally and I'm not sure if converting data this way is a best solution?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-07**:
This is really a separate question. Please open a new one.